# How to do the loop and solve the following

Tags: c#, .net, math

I'm supposed to code a program that writes out a division just like in school.

Example:

```
13:3=4.333333333333
13
 1
 10
  10
   10....
```

So my approach was:
Solve the division then get the solution in a `List`.
Then question if the first number (in this case 1) is divisible by 3.
If not put it down and add the second number and so on...

I managed to do this the first time. It's sloppy but works. The problem is that it only works with numbers that when divided get to have a decimal in it.
Exapmle:
[123:13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD3mY.png)

This is the first code:

```
do
{
    for (int number = 1; number <= divNum; number++)
        if (number % divisor == 0) countH++;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        Console.Write(" ");

    if ((c = divNum % divisor ) < divisor )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" " + ((divNum- (countH * divisor ))) * 10);
    }
    else Console.WriteLine(" " + (divNum- (countH * divisor )));
    c = divNum % divisor ;

    if (c < divisor )
    {
        divNum = c * 10;
    }

    count++; countH = 0;


} while ((divNum >= divisor ) && (count < x));
```

Any ideas or help? Sorry if this is a bad question.

************ added
Try of a better explanation:

1 cant be divided by 13, so it goes down, we get the 2 down and try 12 divided by 13, still nothing so we get the 3 down and try 123:13, 13 goes 9 times in 123 so we have 123-9*13 = 6 the six goes down we write 9 in the result. We try 6:13 not going so we drop a 0 next to 6. Next we try 60:13, 13 goes 4 times so 60-4*13 = 8, we get the 8 down. And so on..

```
123:13=9.46153....
123
  60
   80
    20
     70
      50
       ....
```

Comment: Please format your code, it is hard to read if it is scattered that much.

Comment: If divination is a concern, watch out for the ides of March.

Comment: You can use ternary operator to trim if else hell. and logic gates to simplify process

Comment: Please explain in your question - what is "a", what is "b". Try to give meaningful names and the code will be easier to read and fix.

Comment: Sorry, still new to all this,
a is the number we want to divide, a bi is the number we divide it with.
13:3=4.3333333333....
Where a=13, and b=3

Comment: @aiku "Give meaningful names in your code" doesn't mean "give an incoherent, fragmentary non-explanation hidden in a comment"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Not the fastest solution most likely, but should do the job.

```
var number = 123;
var b = 12;
int quotient;
double remainder = number;
var x = 10;
do
{
    quotient = (int)Math.Floor(remainder / b);
    remainder = remainder - (quotient * b);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        Console.Write(" ");

    remainder *= 10;
    Console.WriteLine(" " + remainder);    
    count++;    

} while ((remainder > 0) && (count < x));
```

Comment: This is similar  to what i have now. maybe ill add some new explanation in the question.

Comment: The added explanation still doesn't really help with what the real question is, then. Can you try to give me an example that doesn't work: what the numbers are, what happens, what is meant to happen?

Comment: I'm sorry for the really late reply. I had to do something like this (also sorry for the video to be in Croatian)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoTIBlVfcmk

I thought I was on a good way to solve.